# Absolute search against wordpress api

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search, api

I am using the below to search to check if a product category is already created

```
$params = [
    'search' => "category1"
];
$searchedparaCat = $woocommerce->get('products/categories', $params);
```

using https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php

This works however it seems to do searches as 'like' instead of absolute. For example the above could return

"category11", "category14", "category14552"....

What I need really is an absolute search so that it will ONLY return a category with the give search term as its slug. Is this possible? I know I can iterate over the returned results and filter them but before I go down that route can this be done via the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches are always fuzzy, not exact. You might be looking for the `slug` parameter here. From the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-product-categories), it reads **Limit result set to resources with a specific slug.**

I assume it should fit your case and it would only return the categories that match the slug provided.